# SQL Server 2014 equivalent to GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, string-aggregation

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have a `country` table and `city` table

Country Table

```
   ID | Code
   ---+-------
   1  |  USA
   2  |  UK
```

City Table

```
   ID | Code  | CountryID
  ----+-------+------------
   1  |  JSN  |    1
   2  |  REH  |    2
```

For some reason, we have a table that links country ID with different city ID as below

`CountryCity` table

```
CountryID | CityID
----------+-------
    1     |   2
    1     |   4
    2     |   3
    1     |   5
    2     |   6
```

Now what I want is using table `CountryCity`

I want to group all the cities to its country in one row or multiple column as below

```
CountryID | CountryCode | CitiesCode
----------+-------------+-----------
    1           USA        JSN , NYC
```

I want to use the mapping in `CountryCity` and get the codes from `country` & `city` table

I tried below but still it's returning it in different rows

```
select
    cc.countryID,
    cc.countryCode,
    citiedCode = stuff((select ',' + c.code
                        from dbo.city c
                        where cc.cityID = c.id
                        for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from 
    dbo.[CountryCity] cc
inner join 
    country on country.id = cc.countryid 
where 
    cc.statusid = 1 and country.statusid = 1
```

Comment: Please tag the version of sql server.

Comment: I think you should use `countryID` in your subquery. assuming `city` table have every row come with correspond `countryID`, something like `cc.CountryID = c.CountryID`

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017. The oldest SQL Server version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2016 by the way. Why are you using SQL Server 2014?

Comment: As for your current problem, you still need to *group* the rows before calculating the aggregate. The XML technique will aggregate all the results of the *subquery* by converting them to XML with empty. tag names, but the *outer* query still has to group the data

Comment: `CountryCity` has a many to one relationship to `Country` in your `FROM`. Why would you *not* expect multiple rows? If you want to aggregate the cities, `CountryCity` needs to be in your aggregation too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused because there is an extraneous `countryId` in the `city` table.  Just ignore it.

If you want one row per country, then don't do a join in the outer query.  Do the join in the inner query:

```
select co.countryID, co.countryCode,
       stuff((select ',' + c.code
              from dbo.city c join
                   countrycity cc
                   on cc.cityid = c.id
              where cc.countryid =  co.id
              for xml path(''), type
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
            ) as citiedCode
from country co;
```

Your sample data does not have any `statusid` columns, so I removed that logic.  You can include that logic in the appropriate place depending on the table.